# 500 server error in django

Tags: django, ubuntu

My project works fine on my PC, then I updated it on the server. I have 500 error (Server Error). In logs (apache2 error.log) there no errors, if I choose debug true, everything is ok. I think that problem contains with django, but I cant find any logs, to fix bugs.
Server:

```
Linux 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Django 1.5. How to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is running fine on debug, you may have missed to set up your allowed host:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["domain.com"]
```

Also make sure that you have a valid email address in ADMINS, so you can get tracebacks via email in production.